# JTable return associative array instead of object

Tags: jtable

I am using the JTable class, but I have an issue, at the moment I export the data I get from the table via this way:

```
$table = $this->getTable('Articles');
$table->load($id);

$properties  = $table->getProperties(1);
return ArrayHelper::toObject($properties, 'JObject');
```

But this spits out a Object. Now I want to spit out an array, so I can access the data via the $array['keyname'] way. (Instead of $array->keyname right now)

But how do I do that?

```
return ArrayHelper::toObject($properties, 'Array');
```

I tried the above but obviously that is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$table->getProperties()` already returns an array. You need to remove `ArrayHelper::toObject()` call which converts the array to an object.